# Load complete history in P4V Helix Client

Tags: perforce, p4v

The history tab dynamically loads more of the version history when scrolling down, is there any way of loading the entire version history without having to tediously continue scrolling until you hit the first revision? The reason is that when you try and use the Find command it only considers the items in the list view that are currently loaded.

Comment: One way is to move to the command line and learn to use it. `p4 filelog` and `p4 changes` are pretty easy commands to learn, here's the docs: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v17.1/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_filelog.html and  https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.1/cmdref/p4_changes.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bryan Pendleton's recommendation.  Running via command line is quick and you can massage the results however you'd like.  The only thing I would add is to check out the current documentation.  Googling perforce documentation is unfortunately littered with old results.  Bryan's links are 3 and 5 years old.

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_filelog.html
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_changes.html